# Keycloak admin console - invalid username or password

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

I have keycloak standalone running in ubuntu and I configured postgre for database. Added a new user using **add-user-keycloak.sh** as below

```
./add-user-keycloak.sh -r master -u admin -p pa$$word
```

The above command says

> Added 'admin' to '/opt/keycloak-15.0.2/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user

I am not sure why its says adding user to this json file when I have the database configured. Or is that normal ? Because when I checked my database I could see a new row is added with admin in user_entity table. Tried to create coupe of users using same above method but I still get "invalid username or password" error when I try to logging to admin console. I am accessing the keayloak remotely. Not sure what I am missing. A help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where are you trying to login? admin-console or account-console?

Comment: I am trying to login to admin console.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your expectation that password `pa$$word` is configured for `admin` user is wrong. Problem is `$$`, which have special meaning (it depends on used shell), see example from my shell:

```
# echo "pa$$word"
pa4877word
```

BTW: `$$` returns the process ID of the shell you are in

So use command in the format which will intepred `pa$$word` as `pa$$word` and not as `pa<shell pid>word`:

```
./add-user-keycloak.sh -r master -u admin -p 'pa$$word'
```

and then you can be sure, that you have configured `pa$$word` correctly.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I deleted all ids and added new user. I guess password usage was wrong. It works now. Thank you.